# How do I validate restful parameters in rails at the routing level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I currently have the following restful url:

```
/questions/2011/05/
```

My route for questions is:

```
match 'questions/:year/:month/' => 'Questions#month'
```

How can I validate the above year and month parameters at the route level so that:

1. year and month are integers
2. min/max length of year = 4
3. min/max length of month = 2

In django, I can do the above with the following line:

```
url(r'^questions/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', 'questions.views.month'),
```

I'm looking through the rails guide and googling around and I cannot find the corresponding functionality at the routing level.  Is the above meant to be done at the controller level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the constraints option to the match method options hash.

```
match 'questions/:year/:month/' => 'questions#month', :constraints => {:year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/}
```

[Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) | [APIDock Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing)